# List all friends for a userid SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables a **user** table (user_id, fname, lname, dob, etc) and a **are_friends** table 
(userA_id, userB_id). I have been trying to do this query for a while now, I need it to list all friends for a user_id.

What I have got so far,

```
SELECT
  U.user_id,
  U.fname,
  U.lname 
FROM are_friends A, user U
WHERE
  A.user_id = U.user_id
  AND (
    A.user_id = 1
    OR A.user_id IN (SELECT userB_id FROM are_friends WHERE userA_id = 1)
  );
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You tagged your question with MySQL **and** Oracle. What are your really using?

Comment: Im using SQLPLUS under oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Try using an [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) like this:

```
SELECT u2.user_id, u2.fname, u2.lname
FROM user u
INNER JOIN are_friends f ON f.userA_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN user u2 ON u2.user_id = f.userB_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

You can change the `WHERE` clause to specifically get the friends of another user id.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will try this and get back to you. Thanks once again.